# Как включить подсветку синтаксиса на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть сайт. Там много кода на Java.
Как включить подсветку синтаксиса как на других сайтах? То есть нужно чтобы я добавлял код на Java, а сайт автоматически подсвечивал его как в Sublime Text допустим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте jquery плагин [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/).